# Create Figure with subfigures from .svg files

Tags: graphics, subfloats, svg, overleaf

I am trying to create a number of figures in Overleaf which consist of several subpictures. To get highly resoluted pictures, I have saved them in .svg format. I have read different posts and learned that the svg package utilizes the subfigure (or subfig?) package to achieve this. I have tried to create my images in different ways, nothing really works. I have also read that there are workarounds using inkscape, but those seem outdated.. What code can I use in LaTeX to achieve what I want?

One of the versions I have tried is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
       \includesvg[width=\linewidth]{sul_trends.svg}
       \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

But it produces an error: `Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> } l.322 \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}`

Comment: `subfigure` is a deprecated package. Use  the `subfig` or `subcaption` packages. The `\label` without caption is also not useful

Comment: Just noticed: `svg` loads `subfig`, so `subcaption` does fail then!

Answer (score 3):

Since `svg` loads `subfig`, which is in turn incompatible with `subcaption`,there's not left: Use `\subfloat` inside of a `figure` environment.

The `subfigure` package is obsolete and shouldn't be used any longer!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{sampleimage.jpg}}\qquad
\subfloat[Second.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{sampleimage.jpg}}\qquad
\subfloat[Third.]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{sampleimage.jpg}}\qquad
\caption{Three sub-floats.}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! It looks nice, but when I try to use a .svg file as filename I get the error 'LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg.', even though the svg package is loaded..any idea why?

Comment: I used `\includegraphics` instead of `\includesvg` because I was too lazy to generate some `.svg` files

Comment: @sequence_hard: Have you `--shell-escape` enabled. I can't test right now however

Comment: yes, I also tried \includesvg. Now I get the error 'Package xkeyval Error: `scale' undefined in families ` svg.sty''. I also tried inserting '\textwidth' instead, which also gives an error. Do you know how I can resolve this issue? Sorry for all the questions, I am a total LaTeX beginner..

Comment: if '--shell-escape' is not enabled by default I guess it s disabled, as i dd not make any changes. What would that command achieve?

Comment: @sequence_hard: Actually, I've never used `svg` before. The `scale` option isn't availabe,but `width` and `height`

Comment: I'll check later on being at home on my more powerful machine, I am leaving right now my workplace.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Using the code as '\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
        \subfloat[]{\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{ARGperisolate.svg}}\qquad' brings me back to 'LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg.'

Comment: Also tried removng the .svg at the end of the file as stated in the svg package manual, but to no avail

Comment: @sequence_hard `\includesvg` from the `svg` package requires `inkscape`, which unfortunately isn't available on Overleaf's servers at present. Sorry about that! As an alternative, you can export the `.svg` to `.pdf` (which would still be high-res) on your own machine, and then upload the `.pdf` to your Overleaf project.

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem! Then I will convert everything and make subfigures from pdf. Thank you!

Comment: @LianTzeLim: Thanks, I figured that out too in the meantime.

Comment: @sequence_hard: Yes, in this case you can use `subcaptions` package as well